# Reverse engineering Bezier Curve

Tags: bezier-curves, mathematics, conversion

I am writing a script that involves creating bezier curves from poly curves. Is there any way to return the simplest bezier curve that can be made from a series of points?

Basically I want to convert this:
[image: Poly Curve]

To this:[image: Bezier Curve]
If someone could give me some pointers I'd really appreciate it. I haven't done much calculus since highschool.

Thanks!

Comment: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6304825) points to a good algorithm and a C language implementation. There's a reference to a numpy implementation in one of the comments.

Comment: Thank you will check this out!

Comment: That numpy script looks awesome! Exactly what I need and simple enough to apply and actually understand what it’s doing. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to write a script *only* for this purpose, and not trying to incorporate this into a larger more complex script, note that you can already do this in Blender with the "Add Curve: Simplify Curves+" add-on.

Starting with a poly curve:

1. Switch to edit mode
2. Right click on the curve -> Set Spline Type -> Bezier
3. Right click on the curve -> Curve Simplify (needs the Simplify Curves+ add-on)
4. In the "Simplify Curves" dialog, increase the "Error" value to reduce the number of control points.

Comment: Thank you! Yeah it's just part of a script i'm writing to create custom bevel objects for roads, convert to mesh, grab certain loops and turn them back into bezier curves so i can manipulate the curves smoothly. Right now i'm debating whether I should just offset the road spline for striping, but I know offset can be touch and go for bezier curves.